# Creating testcases using a dataset to be run by TestNG

Tags: java, junit, automation, testng

I have a project where same code applies to all TCs , the only difference would be the data set. If I use a single TestCase decorated by @Test looping through the dataset, I would not get an intuitive report.

I want to loop through the dataset line by line creating Testcases on the fly via a baseClass in the framework.

Is the only way to accomplish this is using DataProvider or Is their any other solution for this in TestNG or I need to opt for a different test runner or would I need a different language altogether?

Comment: Do you have any code sample you could share ? I simply include a comment about the test case in the DataProvider object for reporting. It is very rudimentary but works. What are your reporting requirements ?